# Changing Columns interval in Razor asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

I have a chart in razor and it seems that it's not displaying all the column names. I searched about it and it seems to be something about column interval.
However, I couldn't find it . Anyone knows how?
My code :

```
@{

var db = Database.Open("InspectionBanqueContext");
var data = db.Query("SELECT count(code_ligneRapport) as nombre ,classe_anomalie as classe  FROM rapportAnomalie, ligneRapportAnomalie ,refAnomalie where  refAnomalie.code_anomalie=ligneRapportAnomalie.code_anomalie And ligneRapportAnomalie.code_rapport= 7  GROUP BY refAnomalie.classe_anomalie ");
var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 500, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
    .AddTitle("Classification des Rapport par nombre d'anomalie pour chaque classe")
    .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
         xValue: data, xField: "classe",
         yValues: data, yFields: "nombre")
         .SetXAxis("Classe")
         .SetYAxis("Nombre d'Anomalie")
         .Write();

}
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/2yosab4.png it doesn't show all fields on the X axis

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code in a sample project and the only reason I could find why x values are missing for some columns is because if the x value for those coordinates where empty string. So you need to ensure your data that is going in the chart has values. I tried to reproduce it as best possible.

Model:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string classe { get; set; }
    public int nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = new List<ChartData> 
    {
        new ChartData{ classe = "A", nombre = 15 },
        new ChartData{ classe = "B", nombre = 20 },
        new ChartData{ classe = "", nombre = 25 },
        new ChartData{ classe = "C", nombre = 10 }
    };

    return View(data);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.ChartData>
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 500, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
        .AddTitle("Classification des Rapport par nombre d'anomalie pour chaque classe")
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "column",
            xValue: Model, xField: "classe",
            yValues: Model, yFields: "nombre")
                .SetXAxis("Classe")
                .SetYAxis("Nombre d'Anomalie")
        .Write();
}
```

Comment: @OmarChaabouni I can't think of any other reason honestly other than as I have already shown in my code above. But just as a precaution set a breakpoint to see what your `data` variable holds after executing the query.

Comment: You know how to parse the data object?

Comment: @OmarChaabouni Easiest will be to inspect your `data` variable from VS or you can also dump it into Debug window using `Debug.WriteLine()` and there are many other ways. Also it would be better to send your data from your Action rather than having data-related code in your view. Do like I did in sample